# Android Emulator doesn't run in VS2015 on a virtual machine

Tags: android-emulator, visual-studio-2015

On a VMware Workstation I couldn't run the Android Emulator in Visual Studio 2015. I got the message: "...unable to verify that the virtual machine is running..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the emulator needs Hyper-V. To enable it do the following:

- stop you VM
- add `hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = "FALSE"` to your .vmx file
- change the settings:
  [image: Virtualize-Settings]
  Now you're good to go!

Comment: Does this work nicely? I have been trying for quite some time to find a fast Android emulator that also runs within a VMWare Guest. Genymotion, Xamarin, MS all did not work. (In my case, additionally it may also be a problem with the Linux host missing drivers.)

Comment: Where did go to access the Virtual Machine Settings window?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above: After alot of searching I got this working. Hope this helps. I found it in the comments on MSDN Article for Android Emulator with Visual Studio 2015

The new images might work if you disable OpenGL by going to Program Files (or Program Files x86 if you're on a 64-bit machine) \ Microsoft XDE \ 10.0.0.0 \ SKUs \ Android \ xdesku.xml and deleting this line: GuestDisplayProvider = "VsEmulator.OpenGLGuestDisplay". However, without OpenGL turned on you will not be able to take advantage of many of the new features